# "invalid name syntax" Error while casting a relation name to regclass

Tags: postgresql

I have a line of code (code below) that drops a table upon certain condition (EDIT: And a second where I verify the existence of relation by casting its name to regclass). It is dynamic and take its parameter from information_schema. 
In it, I cast the table_name to regclass (I'm unsure if it is needed).

The problem arise from a table that contains a space character in its name (I think this is the source of the problem). Casting it to regclass returns an "invalid syntax name" error.

Anyone encountered this problem and has a solution or an explanation?

I found that calling has_table_privilege on the table returns that error too. 
EDIT:
It can be tested simply by creating a table like "foo bar" and calling 
select has_table_privilege('me','_test.foo bar','SELECT')
It returns the error.

```
EXECUTE format('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 1$I.%2$I;',NEW.nom_schema,_new_tbl::regclass);

SELECT to_regclass(concat('"',NEW.nom_schema,'"','.',_new_tbl))) is not null
```

It should simply drop the table, but the space character seems to break the casting.

Comment: How is it I cannot cast a table_name containing spaces to regclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `%I` in `format()` there is no need to cast the string.

I think you just want:

```
format('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %I.%I;', NEW.nom_schema, _new_tbl);
```

The placeholder `%I` will take care of proper quoting if needed.

---

If you are dealing with columns from `information_schema`, you need to first cast them to text, due to the somewhat strange data type of those columns, e.g. `table_name::text::regclass`

Comment: It does fixes the drop table but not the second one (SELECT to_regclass(concat('"',NEW.nom_schema,'"','.',_new_tbl))) is not null)

Comment: Got it, I hardcoded double quotes in the concatenation.